# How could I draw mesh line for nurbs surface in asymptote?

Tags: asymptote

For a bezier patch, I can define the patch as a surface and plot mesh line, as in the example code:

```
import three;

size(10cm);
currentlight=Viewport;

surface s=surface(patch(new triple[][] {
  {(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,0),(2,0,0)},
  {(0,1,0),(1,0,1),(1,0,1),(2,1,0)},
  {(0,1,0),(1,0,-1),(1,0,-1),(2,1,0)},
  {(0,2,0),(1,2,0),(1,2,0),(2,2,0)}}));
//plot surface
draw(s,yellow);
//plot mesh line
draw(s.s[0].vequals(0.5),squarecap+2bp+blue,currentlight);
draw(s.s[0].uequals(0.5),squarecap+2bp+red,currentlight);
```

How can I do the similar thing for a nurbs surface?

[image]

Comment: @marmot, search for NURBSsurface.asy

Comment: Would you mind to append a link or even an MWE to your nice question?

Comment: Observing surface.asy file it seems not possible. You have to do by yourself.